# Jquery.tablesorter.pager Pagination VIew All option

Tags: jquery-pagination, tablesorter

I am trying to add view all option to the

> pagesize option

Something silmilar to below:

```
<select class="pagesize">
<option value="10">10 per page</option>
<option value="20">20 per page</option>
<option value="all">View All</option>
</select>
```

for JQuery tablesorter.
How is that possible?
Please share some example or tutorial.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Since you control the pagesize selector, just add a really large value in the view all option:

```
<select class="pagesize">
  <option value="10">10 per page</option>
  <option value="20">20 per page</option>
  <option value="500">View All</option>
</select>
```

I tried it and it works without causing any errors, but if you want to be more specific, you can add a bit of code to make it more exact:

```
$(function(){
  var rows = $('table.tablesorter')[0].config.totalRows;
  $('select.pagesize').find('option:contains("All")').val(rows);
});
```

Comment: thanks fudgey for your wonderful esponse. I want to choose your second option. It works fine with the Jquery example but when I add the function to my JSP code and try to VIEW ALL, the script stops working. Any clue?

Comment: fudgey, I resolved the issue. It was a case issue. Thanks again.